# openssl.exe smime -decrypt not working if called from powershell / c# / .bat

Tags: c#, powershell, openssl

This works from command line:

```
openssl.exe smime -decrypt -in C:\SdI\N1N3\FO.04669240287.2019231.1930.901.zip.p7m.enc -inform der -binary -out C:\SdI\N1N3\FO.04669240287.2019231.1930.901.zip.p7m -recip C:\SdI\Certificates\MGLFNC82H02Z112Z.EDYAT001.CIFRA.P12.pem -passin pass:123456789
```

The same command does not work from powershell / run from c# code / executed in a .bat (and throw always the same error below)

```
.\openssl.exe "smime" -decrypt –in "C:\SdI\N1N3\FO.04669240287.2019231.1930.901.zip.p7m.enc" –inform "der" –binary -out "C:\SdI\N1N3\FO.04669240287.2019231.1930.901.zip.p7m" –recip "C:\SdI\Certificates\MGLFNC82H02Z112Z.EDYAT001.CIFRA.P12.pem" -passin "pass:123456789"
```

Error:

```
.\openssl : No recipient certificate or key specified
At line:1 char:1
```

All other openssl commands works from both cmd / powershell / bat; any idea?

Thank you

Comment: Sorry guys,
it was an issue with the "-" char transformed by MS Word to "û" in the command
Thank you

Comment: been there, done that ;)